# How do I change the path for the Apache Service in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp

After I have changed the ports for my Apache server, and I try and run it, it comes up with this error message:

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: "C:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

I think this might be because I tried to download Apache separately from XAMPP, and I stored the httpd in that file location. However, I have deleted that file and that area, and I think XAMPP is trying to access that file when it doesn't exist. So how do I change XAMPP apache and control panel settings to the desired field?